# Difference between a ring and a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Their descriptions seem pretty similar. Is a ring the same as a field except it uses abstracted versions of addition and multiplication instead of only classical addition and multiplication as in a field?

I've also already seen the proposed "other answer" and it didn't really answer my question, it was much more convoluted than necessary. Honestly all I'm looking for is a one-line answer.

Comment: Both rings and fields use "abstracted" addition and multiplication. In fact, fields are a special case of rings, namely the ones in which you require all nonzero elements to have multiplicative inverses.

Comment: So a ring is like a field except with no guarantee of the existence of inverse elements under + and x, kind of like the difference between a group and semigroup, which makes rings more generalized.

Comment: If $R$ is a ring then it is a field iff $R-\{0\}$ equipped with multiplication is a commutative group.

Comment: Okay, so the main difference between a field and ring is that a field's elements commute under multiplication but that you ignore the 0 element of the set under multiplication.